# Question about the Off-topic close reason vs migration close reasons

Tags: discussion

Looking at an example here: https://serverfault.com/questions/526087/how-do-i-direct-inbound-network-traffic-to-a-specific-internal-ip-based-on-the-r

The question I have is, I know voretaq's close reason here: https://meta.serverfault.com/a/5606/7861 made the new list and seems to be used quite often now.

[image]

But since this has been implemented it's been the go to instead of the old "migration" found here:

[image]

In the example at the top, it seems like the better choice would be to simply migrate it than to force the user to decide if they want to pursue it on SU or not.

Is the idea to force most of these questions back on the user to figure out if they want to ask on Superuser or just let the question die, or is there a valid reason for picking the "close" vs. the "migration choice.

The same applies to the SO choices...

If this is a duplicate or already been answered, please let me know.  I searched Meta here and on Meta.SE and couldn't find anything.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not a fan of those close reasons for the issues you have cited here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the idea is to force the question back onto the asker to figure out what to do.

When we were rebelling against the crap being migrated in to us from SO, one thing I found was that only a minority of people would follow their migrated questions here.  So migrated questions, even if they were good ones, would languish - no replies if there were comments seeking clarification, no accept if a good answer was given...

Because of this and because many of us don't want to migrate crap to another site, we treat "close without migrating" as the default.

I'll only pick a "Belongs on..." close reason if a question is clearly on-topic on the other site and clearly really good.  If there's any doubt in my mind about either the topicality or quality, I'll find some other close reason.  Before it was taken away, I'd pick the generic "off-topic" reason, now it's either one of the "May be suitable for ..." or one of the other reasons.  *Anything* in preference to possibly migrating crap.

Comment: Makes sense, especially the "languish" part.  I can see a good reason to migrate being if the question would have lasting value for future visitors as well, even if the OP never bothers to come back and accept the answer after migration.

Comment: +1 -- the "You should ask on" close reasons are certainly not ideal (they will probably go away), but migrating has its own problems.

Comment: Accepted - and the question is pretty irrelevant now with the new close reasons set.